# Proxmox port forwarding to Container behind NAT

Tags: networking, port-forwarding, proxmox

We have recently bought a server from the Hetzner server auction and want to migrate our previous root server.
Previously we used only windows server, but now we want to set it up a bit more modular with proxmox.

We have a single public IP address, so we chose to use NAT with a 10.0.0.0/24 internal subnet.

The containers can access the internet, so this works fine.

But we can't connect to servers which run inside the containers over custom ports.

How can I properly forward the ports? We tried the routing and  port forwarding as listed below. Something went wrong, the ports arent open, as shown by portscans.
There is currently only a firewall in the Proxmox host, the server host firewall is disabled, so I dont know why traffic should be blocked.

This is the current setup of the proxmox network interface:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

iface lo inet6 loopback

auto eno1
iface eno1 inet static
        address public.ipv4/26
        gateway public.gateway
        up route add -net public.ipv4 netmask 255.255.255.192 gw public.ipv4 dev eno1
# route public.ipv4.range.start/26 via public.ipv4.range.start+1

iface eno1 inet6 static
        address public.ipv6/128
        gateway fe80::1

auto vmbr0
iface vmbr0 inet static
        address 10.0.0.1/24
        bridge-ports none
        bridge-stp off
        bridge-fd 0

        post-up   echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
        post-up echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/eno1/proxy_arp
        post-up iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s '10.0.0.0/24' -o eno1 -j MASQUERADE
        post-down iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -s '10.0.0.0/24' -o eno1 -j MASQUERADE
        post-up iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i vmbr0 -p tcp --dport 28967 -j DNAT --to 10.0.0.4:28967
        post-up iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i vmbr0 -p udp --dport 28967 -j DNAT --to 10.0.0.4:28967
        post-down iptables -t nat -D PREROUTING -i vmbr0 -p tcp --dport 28967 -j DNAT --to 10.0.0.4:28967
        post-down iptables -t nat -D PREROUTING -i vmbr0 -p udp --dport 28967 -j DNAT --to 10.0.0.4:28967

iface vmbr0 inet6 static
        address public.ipv6+1/64
```

iptables -L -t nat:

```
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DNAT       tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:28967 to:10.0.0.4:28967
DNAT       udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:28967 to:10.0.0.4:28967

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
MASQUERADE  all  --  10.0.0.0/24          anywhere
```

The eno1 interface was autogenerated by their installation script.
We added the bridge and the NAT etc.

Client config:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
iface lo inet6 loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
        address 10.0.0.4/24
        gateway 10.0.0.1
```

Client container has currently no firewall.

We are relatively inexperienced with networking inside a KWM host, so any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Your source NAT (MASQUERADE) rule looks wrong. It should match traffics with destination (instead of source) IP of 10.0.0.4/32 (or 10.0.0.0/24, depends on what you want). (Or you can match with e.g. `-o vmbr0`.)

Comment: Hmm but since the container uses the host as its default gateway no source NAT should be necessary. (Not sure what `pointtopoint public.ipv4` doed though.)

Comment: Tom the configuration depends on the usecase, a p2p could be usable but I agree not at all points. a Dnat is 1.2.3.4:3333 -> 10.10.10.10:6666 which means that on the pub redirect the port 3333 to a lan desto. on port 6666 in this example. as you did not show the iptables command, I can only imagine that you used NAT which only translate between the two ips but not on a specific port

Comment: The above contains all the iptables commands I used. What do I have to change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We figured something out and I'll post it here in case its useful for anyone. (Disclaimer: We put this together after hours of trial and error, this might only work for our hosting provider. I am not a Linux network expert by any means.)

`/etc/network/interfaces`:

```bash
source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
iface lo inet6 loopback

auto eno1
iface eno1 inet static
    address <hostpublicip>/26
    gateway <hostgateway>
    up route add -net <hostgateway-1> netmask 255.255.255.192 gw <hostgateway> dev eno1
    post-up echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward # add this line

auto vmbr0
iface vmbr0 inet static
    address 10.0.0.1/24
    bridge-ports none
    bridge-stp off
    bridge-fd 0

    post-up iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s '10.0.0.0/24' -o eno1 -j MASQUERADE
    post-down iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -s '10.0.0.0/24' -o eno1 -j MASQUERADE
    post-down iptables -t nat -F
    post-up   iptables -t raw -I PREROUTING -i fwbr+ -j CT --zone 1
    post-down iptables -t raw -D PREROUTING -i fwbr+ -j CT --zone 1
```

The eno1 interface was already set up by the install script of our hosting provider ([Hetzner](https://community.hetzner.com/tutorials/install-and-configure-proxmox_ve)), we added the `post-up` line to enable IP forwarding on boot.
We created the vmbr0 interface in proxmox and set up a subnet address, you can choose any address range you like. We went with 10.0.0.0/24.
Then you need to change the file entry according to our example above. The lines are required as they are (except the IP of course).
If there are any ipv6 interfaces, leave them alone.

Now when you create containers/VMs you need to set the IPv4 address to static and choose any that fits your subrange (`10.0.0.xxx/24`), and set the gateway as `10.0.0.1`.

All the port forwards are defined in the file `/etc/network/interfaces.d/port_forwards` (needs to be created by the user, all files in that path are loaded into the above main file with the `source` line). The IP address in the port forwards is the IP address you assigned to the container during creation.

```bash
# your network interface
iface vmbr0 inet static
    # minecraft container as example
    post-up port_forward -t 10.0.0.201 -p tcp -d 22     -s 22201 # external port 22201 for direct ssh to container
    post-up port_forward -t 10.0.0.201 -p tcp -m -d 25566,25576
    post-up port_forward -t 10.0.0.201 -p udp -m -d 25566,25576
    # follow with all the port forwards you need
```

With a custom port forwarding script called `port_forward` which just abbreviates the `iptables` commands to keep the file readable.
This file must be placed in or linked to `/bin/` so it is loaded before the user partition is mounted.

```bash
#!/bin/bash
# abbr for iptables dnat

usage() { echo "Usage: $0 -t <container_ip> -p <tcp/udp/etc> -d <port> [-s <external port if different>] [-m flag if ports will be comma separated list, not compatible with -s]" 1>&2; exit 0; }

while getopts t:p:d:s::m flag
do
    case "${flag}" in
        t) target_ip=${OPTARG};;
        p) protocoll=${OPTARG};;
        d) dest_port=${OPTARG};;
        s) src_port=${OPTARG};;
        m) multiport=1 ;;
        *) usage ;;
    esac
done

if [[ -z "$src_port" ]]; then
    src_port="$dest_port"
fi

if [[ "$multiport" -eq 1 ]]; then
    iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eno1 -p "$protocoll" -m multiport --dports "$dest_port" -j DNAT --to "$target_ip"
else
    iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eno1 -p "$protocoll" --dport "$src_port" -j DNAT --to "$target_ip":"$dest_port"
fi
```

Everytime the files are changed, iptables needs to be reset like so:

```bash
iptables --flush
iptables -t nat --flush
iptables --delete-chain
ifreload --all
```

This can be put in a file as well, we named it `reload_network` and placed it in the `/usr/local/bin/` folder to access as a command.

Comment: This looks really awesome, and exactly what I'm looking for. Could you explain it just a little bit more for us more newbie folk? Like what do I need to change in the files for it to apply to me? I'm pretty sure I need to switch out the post public IP and gateway, but do I manually make the port forwards file? And I write all those out? Or is that somehow auto generated by the script you wrote at the end? Also could the IP tables flush bit at the very very end also be scripted into a command? I think you're under something here You could have a highly rated GitHub if you just expanded the docs

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @J.Griffin, I tried to clarify my answer. Let me know if something is still uncelar. Unfortunately this was already some months ago and I already forgot some of the details. Shame on me for not documenting it better.